# How to get the P-value from a known Friedman's chi-squared value

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, python, scipy

Provided I have the value of the Friedman's chi-squared statistic, is there any way to get the corresponding P-value without copying the whole table of critical values in my Python program?

Comment: Are you speaking about [Friedman test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test)?

Comment: Yes. More specifically I have converted the Kendall's W value to Friedman's chi-squared in order to get the P-value.

Comment: The p-value is obtained from chi-square distribution function with degrees of freedom = number_of_groups_k - 1. That is, find something called like "cdfchisq()" function in your python library. The p-value is `1-the_function(your_chisq_value,k-1)`.

Comment: you are right, the function is called chisqprob() and can be accessed like this:

    from scipy import stats
    stats.chisqprob(chisq, df)

, where 
      
      chisq : array_like or float > 0,
      df : array_like or float, probably int >= 1